# Can't @Autowire repository interface Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

The problem I'm facing is about `@Autowire` the repository interface (UserRepository in my case), I don't know why, but the `@Autowire` is failing.

`UserController` class calls a `@Service` class and this one calls a `@Component` (DAO class), the DAO class is `@Autowiring` the `@Repository`.

**Spring boot main**

```
package com.leagueofsummoners;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import com.leagueofsummoners.persistence.interfaces.UserRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LeagueofsummonersApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LeagueofsummonersApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
            ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html");
            ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");

            container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error404Page, error500Page);
        });
    }
}
```

**DTO CLASS (Entity)**

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id_user")
private Long idUser;

@Column(nullable = false, name = "summoner_name")
private String summonerName;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String email;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String avatar;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String firma;
@Column(nullable = false, name = "permission_level")
private PermissionLevels permissionLevel;

public UserDTO() {
}
```

**Repository interface**

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import com.leagueofsummoners.model.dto.UserDTO;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<UserDTO, Long> {

    Page<UserDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    UserDTO findByUsernameIgnoringCase(String username);

    UserDTO findByIdUser(int idUser);
}
```

**DAO class (this one failing when autowiring repository class)**

```
@Component
public class UserDAO{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDTO findByUsernameIgnoringCase(String username) {
        return this.userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoringCase(username);
    }
}
```

[Here's a link with the log of the console](https://justpaste.it/t4av)

Comment: Whoever is downvoting me, i'd like to know why did he/she do it :·) (Not bad mod just for learn pruposes) x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to scan for `JpaRepositories` add this annotation on your application Class :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.leagueofsummoners.persistence.interfaces")
```

**EDIT:**

In order to configure the `entityManager` you need to add the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

if you add this dependency it will configure the repositories automatically for you so you don't need to add the`@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: I tried that, but sitll it is failing, seems like the error is different though.
Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1c6c6f24' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'

Comment: @NoOne the autowired issue is solved, that's a different issue i guess

Comment: @NoOne can you add the full stack strace ?

Comment: @NoOne, the problem here is that you don't have an entityManager defined, can you share the dependency you are using for spring boot ?

Comment: Not sure if you mean pom.xml but here it is...
http://pasted.co/0374ac06 , but yeah, im missing entityManager, the guide i was checking misses it aswell. Guess gonna check it anywhere :·). Thanks alot dude.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108721/discussion-between-no-one-and-rafik-beldi).

Comment: You don't need the `@EnableJparepositories` when using Spring boot that is automatically done for you. The key is to configure JPA properly and have the proper dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. If you have the latter dependency you can remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

Comment: Yes that's correct thanks @M.Deinum, he didn't have Spring boot starter data jpa when he first asked, ill edit the answer

Comment: your comment about the dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" being added to the POM fixed everything for me. Great answer.